# Unwanted Italicization of Symbol Text (ArcMap 9.3.1)?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, symbology

So I am running in to a problem that has got me stumped. I'm working on a road systems map, and there are a few symbols with text in the middle. The problem is that the text within the badge, triangle, etc. is randomly becoming italicized. I have gone into the symbol property editor, made sure that the text layer has no italics, rotation, anything. However the text is still being represented in italics when on the map? The symbol itself is not rotated or shifted in any way, just the text inside. I might be missing something simple, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

I am using ArcMap 9.3.1, and if it matters, the MPS Atlas Extension.

Comment: Do you see the problem when you're not using the MPS Atlas Extension?

Answer (score 2):

Try the **Un-Italic** tag for ArcMap to force your text in the symbol to be non-italic

un_italic tags

```
<_ITA> your text </_ITA>
```

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Formatting_tags_available_in_ArcMap

has worked in the past.

(It's more a suggestion to finding a workaround than a full answer.)